# storing datetime.date type in PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime

According to [this](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.8rc1/faq.html#how-can-i-save-a-datetime-date-instance), it's not possible to save `datetime.date` instances in MongoDB using Python and pymongo. It says in the FAQ that it's an unsupported type and to use `datetime.datetime` instead.

However, it's listed (as #9) in the BSON data types page [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/), so is this just out-of-date, or is there a reason I can't use python this data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From mongo docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date

*The [official BSON specification](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) refers to the BSON Date type as the UTC datetime.*

So, there is while it is written as "Date", it's still a datetime in `BSON`. If you want just `date`, you can set the hours/minutes/seconds/ms to `0`.

Also, as specified on the docs about `timestamp`:

*NOTE

The BSON timestamp type is for internal MongoDB use. For most cases, in application development, you will want to use the BSON date type. See Date for more information.*

The difference between `datetime` and `timestamp` is: datetime is an abstraction of date (day, month, year) and time (hour, min, second), and timestamp is the number of seconds since epoch.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the difference between `Timestamp` (#17 in the second link) and `Date` in this case? I thought that the UTC datetime was `Timestamp`?

Comment: @Luciano extended the answer. Timestamp != Datetime. Timestamp is "just a number" of seconds since epoch, Datetime is an abstraction with month, day, year, hour, minutes, seconds. Also: timestamp in mongodb is internal.